# For each Column highlight max value (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Sheet with values going in each column from cells 2:21

I need to highlight the corresponding cell in each column with the maximum value and try to loop through it with a macro. But I only know how to do it for a given hard-coded range..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim zelle As Range
  For Each zelle In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B21")
    If zelle.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("B2:B21")) Then
      zelle.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else
      zelle.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I tried to use a new range for column which I gave the Range ("B:IT") and iterate through that one but that didnt work.

Maybe it's just 2 or 3 lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you. Instead of using hard-coded ranges, it loops through whatever columns are used and adjusts for columns having different "lengths". It assumes a single header row and column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim zelle As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
  With ActiveSheet
    For lCol = 2 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
      lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lCol).End(xlUp).Row
      Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, lCol), .Cells(lLastRow, lCol))
      For Each zelle In rng
        If zelle.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) Then
          zelle.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
          zelle.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
      Next
    Next lCol
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to do this is **without VBA**, is to

1. Calculate the maximum value e.g. at the bottom (=`MAX(A1:A10)`) and
2. To use conditional formatting, highlighting the cell(s) that match the result of your =`MAX(A1:A10)` calculations.

I know that the question referred to VBA, but this makes it dynamic and VBA independent.

[image]

Comment: this is also a nice solution:) but while pushing it over many columns you have to check that for the next columns just the formating should be used. otherwise values may get modified.

Comment: +1 better method that will automaticaly update and avoid time consume loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use variables:

```
Range(Cells(row_var_1, col_var_1),Cells(row_var_2, col_var_2))
```

Where `row_var_1`, `col_var_1`, `row_var_2` and `col_var_2` are variables that may be iterated in your loop.